# Resume Android youtubePlayer in OnResume

Tags: android, onresume

I have a YouTubeBaseActivity it works well, but when I click to go to another activity and then return to that activity, it does not auto play.

I would like it to resume and just start playing the lists again.

Here is the class below :

```
    public class VideoPlayer extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener,View.OnClickListener{

private YouTubePlayerView ytp_mainvideo;
private YouTubePlayer vyouTubePlayer;
private YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener mPlayerStateChangeListener;
boolean fullScreen =false;
TextView txtMainVideo;
List<String> videoList;
static String currentKey="";
Utilities utilities = new Utilities(this);
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save state

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

            if (vyouTubePlayer == null) {
               ytp_mainvideo.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

            }

}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
   if(vyouTubePlayer!=null)
       vyouTubePlayer.cueVideos(videoList);

}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.vidsplash);
    currentKey = utilities.getLicenseKey();
    // Initialize the Main Video Player.

    ytp_mainvideo =(YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubPlayerView);
    ytp_mainvideo.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    txtMainVideo =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_mainvideo);
    txtMainVideo.setOnClickListener(this);
    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] varray = res.getStringArray(R.array.videolist);
    videoList = Arrays.asList(varray);
    mPlayerStateChangeListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoading() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {
            Log.d("ShowCase", "Video Ended");
            if(vyouTubePlayer != null)
                vyouTubePlayer.loadVideos(videoList);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {

        }
    };
    if(currentKey.compareTo("")==0) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewStartActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.text_mainvideo:
            Intent intentsub=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CateMainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentsub);
            break;

    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
    vyouTubePlayer =youTubePlayer;
    youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(mPlayerStateChangeListener);
    if (!wasRestored) {
        // loadVideo() will auto play video
        // Use cueVideo() method, if you don't want to play it automatically
        youTubePlayer.loadVideos(videoList);
        // Hiding player controls
        youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
        youTubePlayer.setOnFullscreenListener(new YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFullscreen(boolean _isFullScreen) {
                fullScreen = _isFullScreen;
            }
        });


    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Toast.makeText(appContext, "BAck", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                VideoPlayer.this);
        alert.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        alert.setIcon(R.drawable.app_icon);
        alert.setMessage("Are You Sure You Want To Quit?");

        alert.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {

                        //you may open Interstitial Ads here
                        finish();
                    }

                });

        alert.setNegativeButton("NO",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
        alert.show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

First Declare YoutubePlayer & seekTime Variable

```
private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
private int seekTime = 0;
```

Then in OnInitializationSuccess method set it to youtubePlayer

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {

    this.youTubePlayer = youTubePlayer;

    if (!wasRestored) {
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId);
    }

}
```

After that, You can store video current time in onPause and can resume the video in onResume method using the trick below

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (youTubePlayer == null) {
        getYouTubePlayerProvider();
    } else {
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, seekTime);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    seekTime = youTubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis();
}
```

It worked fine for me, will work for you as well. Keep Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (vyouTubePlayer == null) {
        ytp_mainvideo.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }
    else {
        vyouTubePlayer.Play();
    }
}
```

I think it gets paused at OnPause, so you need to call `Play()`

Comment: Just tried this, And I get the same result it just shows the loading progress bar, but what is very strange, if I restart the app, and go only to the next activity. And I return it works. But if I go to a 3rd activity which makes server calls and return back to the video player then I get this issue.

Comment: @Youngdev try to remove `OnStop` code

I think it makes this bugs. You don't need to `cueVideos` again in `OnStop`

Comment: I removed the entire OnStop method and nothing changed. Is there a way to recall the Oncreate method ?

Comment: I think I got a clue, when I move to other fragments there is no problem when I return, But the 3rd fragment which also has a Youtube player. re-initializes the youtube player and then when I return to this activity. then i get the issue. So now I know the cause.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to create a 2nd API key. This is very rare issue and I am thankful to Faceles for his responses which lead me to solve it. In this project I am using 2 Youtube Players and so when I moved to the other activity with the second player and returned to this first it never loaded.